# How to create an image a camera would display from an 3D object stored in a .csv file?

Tags: python, csv, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a 3D image of a house stored in a csv file. I would like to know how a camera with f = 400 pix, 640 x 480, would capture photos in different poses. I can display the image in the csv(first image), but I would like to obtain something like the second image.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


#load data
data1 = pd.read_csv('house.csv',sep=' ')
x = data1.drop(data1.columns[[0,2,3]], axis=1)
y = data1.drop(data1.columns[[0,1,3]], axis=1)
z = data1.drop(data1.columns[[1,2,3]], axis=1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
# Hide grid lines
plt.grid(b=None)
ax1.scatter(x,y,z)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('house.png')
```

Heres the images i have:

[image]

[image]

Comment: read the openGL book or a computer graphics lecture to understand the basics of camera models and 3d rendering. You can use opencv projectPoints once you have a 3d model and a camera model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a computer graphics problem. it involves matrix multiplication to transform those points until they are on your image plane. I would suggest that you look up some basic computer graphics math (e.g. OpenGL).

OpenCV has procedures such as [cv::projectPoints()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1019495a2c8d1743ed5cc23fa0daff8c) to handle some of these steps for you. It's not a computer graphics library however.

I'll give you the broad strokes of the math involved:

first you need translation and rotation matrices to move your camera around the scene. these matrices are all 4x4, and your 3D points will be represented as (x,y,z,1) vectors. the extra coordinate makes translation (and more) possible. you multiply the matrices together into one, then apply this one to your points. this transformation moves all points from world space into camera space (the space around the camera moves).

a simple translation by 5 units in +Z would be:

```
>>> T = np.eye(4)
>>> T[0:3,3] = (0, 0, +5)
>>> T
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 5.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

homogenization: check that your points still have that 1 in the last place. if not, divide the point/vector by what's in the fourth coordinate. "the point" is all vectors (x,y,z,1)*w for any w, and (x,y,z,1) is the canonical representation.

now the projection matrix. computer graphics uses a 4x4 matrix here too but I'm not experienced with that formulation. I'll instead uses a 3x3 matrix commonly used in OpenCV. it takes your points as (x,y,z) vectors in camera space, and outputs (x,y,1)*w vectors in screen space (yes, homogenization again).

the camera matrix for a 640x480 camera and 60 degrees horizontal field of view would be:

```
>>> M = np.eye(3)
>>> M[0:2,2] = (640/2, 480/2)
>>> M[0,0] = M[1,1] = (640/2) / atan(60/2 * pi/180)
>>> M
array([[663.42156,   0.     , 320.     ],
       [  0.     , 663.42156, 240.     ],
       [  0.     ,   0.     ,   1.     ]])
```

now you have your points in screen coordinates. draw the points alone or draw lines between them.